# Transform circle to $\mathbb R$: Will any 3 distinct points on the circle work?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, proof-verification, transformation, mobius-transformation

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 3.15

> ([Exer 3.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKZJA.png)) Using the cross ratio, with different choices of $z_k$, find two different Möbius transformations that transform $C[1 + i, 1]$ onto the real axis plus $\infty$. In each case, find the image of the center of the circle.

Note: $C[i+1,1] = \{|z-(i+1)|=1\}$ is the circle with centre (1,1) and radius 1

---

> (Part I) I'm going to try $g=[z,(2,1),(1,2),(0,1)], -g=[z,(2,1),(1,0),(0,1)]$. Please point out and explain any errors.

I observe that that $\pm g$ map $C[i+1,1] \to \mathbb R$. By plugging in $z=(1+i)+e^{i \phi}$, we can show that $\pm g((1+i)+e^{i \phi}) \in \mathbb R$. Then we extend $\pm g$ to be defined for the singularity $z=z_3=i=(0,1)$.

Finally, the images are (WA: [plus](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((i%2B1)-(2%2Bi))((1%2B2i)-(i)))%2F(((i%2B1)-(i))((1%2B2i)-(2%2Bi)))), [minus](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((i%2B1)-(2%2Bi))((1)-(i)))%2F(((i%2B1)-(i))((1)-(2%2Bi)))))

$$\pm g(1+i) = \pm i$$

Did I go wrong anywhere, and why?

> (Part II) Can I actually pick any 3 points on $C[i+1,1]$ to form a required cross-ratio?

By inputting in the 3 points used to make up a cross ratio, into the cross ratio, it seems that the cross ratio will output $0,1,\infty$, soooo it looks like all cross ratios will map 3 distinct points on a circle to the real line.

$\therefore,$ although the question asks for 2 Möbius transformations, there are uncountably $\infty$ly many Möbius transformations/cross-ratios that work, so it seems?

So how will we compute [the images $[i+1,z_1,z_2,z_3]$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((i%2B1)-(z_1))((z_2)-(z_3)))%2F(((i%2B1)-(z_3))((z_2)-(z_1))))? Is it simply that with no particular pattern?

Comment: Why do you think you have gone wrong?

Comment: @Somos I think my ±1 was wrong. Edited. If it's $\pm 1$, then I think I did something wrong because I'm getting something from somewhere inside the circle rather than on the circle and then it gets mapped to the real line...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Part I, you are almost there. The instructions ask you to try

> Using the cross ratio, with different choices of $\ z_i$, find two different
>   Möbius transformations

which you tried to do using $\  g=[z,(2,1),(1,2),(0,1)], \ -g=[z,(2,1),(1,0),(0,1)] \ $ which produces $\ g(z) = (-i z -1 +2i)/(z-i). \ $ Even though $\ -g(z) \ $ is a Möbius transformation, you did **not** get it using a different choice of $\ z_i$. Notice that, by the characteristic property of cross ratio, we immediately know that
  $\ g(2+i) = 0, \ g(1+2i) = 1, \ g(i) = \infty. \ $ and also
 $\ g(1) = -1, \ g(1+i) = i. \ $
It follows that the Möbius transformation $\ h=[z,(2,1),(1,0),(0,1)] \ $ is the same as $\ -g. \ $ Now $\ g \ $ maps the center of the circle to $\ i \ $, and
 $\ -g = h \ $ maps it to $\ -i. \ $

For part II, you can pick any three **distinct** points on the circle and each such choice will produce different Möbius transformations which share the common property that they map the circle one-to-one onto the real line. Depending on the order of the three points, the interior of the circle, including the center, will get mapped one-to-one onto either the upper or lower half plane.

You can think of all Möbius transformations as being **conjugate** to two cases depending on the number of fixed points. Case 1 with one fixed point is a parabolic transformation $\ f(z) = z + a \ $ for some complex constant $\ a $ 
and the fixed point is at infinity. Case 2 with two fixed points is $\ f(z) = b\ z \ $ for some complex constant $\ b $ and the two fixed points are zero and infinity.

There is much more information about all this in the Wikipedia article [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Comment: Thanks Somos! For Part I, are you interpreting that that each of the 3 points for $h$ should have been different from each of the 3 points of $g$, and mine doesn't work because I changed only 1 point?

Comment: I think you have t o take  the instructions literally. Given three distinct points, then $f =[z,z_1,z_2,z_3]$ is the map determined by them. Conversely, given $f$, then the three points are the preimages of $(0,1,\infty).$ It is accidental that $-g$ is **also** a tranformation, but for a **different** triple of points, and since $-0 = 0$ and $-\infty = \infty,$ two of those points are the same as the original triple. I think that the question requires you to use the different triple of points.

Comment: I'm too tired to analyse that, but ayt thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 1):

Write the identity stating that the cross-ratio is preserved:
$$\frac {z - z_1} {z - z_3} \frac {z_2 - z_3} {z_2 - z_1} =
\frac {w - w_1} {w - w_3} \frac {w_2 - w_3} {w_2 - w_1}.$$
Take $z_1, z_2, z_3$ on the circle and $w_1, w_2, w_3$ on the real line. If one of the $w_i$ is infinity, cancel the two factors containing this $w_i$. The function $w(z)$ is the answer.

Comment: Maxim, edited question. In re your answer 1. Will any 3 distinct points on the circle work? 2. How will we compute the images? Please and thank you!

Comment: The formula gives the (unique) linear-fractional transform mapping the three distinct points $z_i$ to the three distinct points $w_i$, which you can verify by substituting $z = z_i$.

Comment: Maxim, it seems you answered (2). How about (1) please? My first attempt was to use specific points on the circle. But actually any 3 distinct will work?

Comment: Take $w_1 = 0, w_2 = \pm 1, w_3 = \infty$. The rhs becomes $\pm w$, therefore $w = \pm (z - z_1)/(z - z_3) (z_2 - z_3)/(z_2 - z_1)$ is a valid choice.

Comment: and $ \pm w$ is on the real line and thus $\pm$ cross ratio works indeed for any 2 distinct points?

Comment: Strictly speaking, we are not making any assumptions about $w$, we've constructed the function $w = w(z)$. A linear-fractional transform maps circles to circles, and a circle is fixed by three points.

Comment: Wait wrong. I mean as $z$ is any 4th point on the circle, $w$ is any 4th point on the real line? Right so, indeed there are uncountably many choices for the cross ratio though the question asks for only 2 Möbius transformations?

Comment: Yes, there are uncountably many choices. Consider that we can add any real number to $w(z)$.

Comment: Wait I mean uncountably many choices of distinct $z_1, z_2, z_3$. Like any 3 distinct points on the circle will give a right answer?

Comment: You know that $w(z_i) = w_i$. You know that a circle is mapped to a circle (a straight line can be treated as a circle going through $\infty$). Why do you think that some choice of $z_i$ might not work?

Comment: Maxim, the problem says 2 different transformations. I thought there are exactly and then the point is to be clever and determine what they are. So apparently this exercise doesn't really say much because it's picking your 3 favourite points on the circle and determining the image you got?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't say "*the* two different mappings".

Comment: Ayt thanks Maxim! ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Part I is right.

Part II No! They have to be distinct. Otherwise, we don't have that they are Möbius transformations. Other than that, yes. Also, I don't see any particular pattern with the images.